# No able to override the custom controllers in strapi

Tags: api, strapi

I am new to strapi.I created my own content-type and tested it in postman,it works fine,however I was not able to override the core controllers as mentioned.Could it be cache or cookie?
Thankyou

Comment: Hello, can you please sent your code.
This feature works well, so I think it comes from your side.

Comment: @Jim..thanks for responding..it actually got resolved..I was doing a blunder..was testing it on find action and given permission to only findOne..it worked perfectly on findOne.
Cheers :)